# TypeError: Class extends value #<DataRepository> is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript

Can I not make a class that extends this `DataRepository` class below and access the key/value inside its JSON file?

```
const fs = require("fs");

class DataRepository {
  constructor(filename) {
    if (!filename) {
      throw new Error("Creating a repository requires a filename");
    }

    this.filename = filename;
    try {
      fs.accessSync(this.filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("data does not exist");
    }
  }

  async getAll() {
    // Open the file called this.filename
    return JSON.parse(
      await fs.promises.readFile(this.filename, {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      })
    );
  }

  async getOneBy(filters) {
    const records = await this.getAll();

    for (let record of records) {
      let found = true;

      for (let key in filters) {
        if (record[key] !== filters[key]) {
          found = false;
        }
      }

      if (found) {
        return record;
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new DataRepository("cales_data.json");
```

This is what I was trying when I got this error:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const DataRepository = require("./repositories/data");

class Address extends DataRepository {
  constructor() {
    this.Address = DataRepository.Address;
    this.Latitude = DataRepository.Latitude;
    this.Longitude = DataRepository.Longitude;
  }
}
```

At the end of the day, I have a json file that is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
{
  'Number (original project order)': 99,
  FIELD2: null,
  Code_Notes: 'Not enough room to code historic preservation approval body',
  'Filler column to reference original sheet': '402 W Santa Clara St',
  City: 15,
  Planning_ID: 'PDC15-051',
  APN: '25938036',
  Total_Number_Parcels: -888,
  Address: '402 W Santa Clara St',
  Description_from_Agenda: 'A Planned Development Permit to allow the construction of a mixed use development with up to 1.04 million square feet for office/retail and up to 325 multi-family attached residences on a 8.93 gross acre site. ',
  Census_Tract: '5008.00',
  Council_District: '3',
  Neighborhood_Planning_Group: '-999',
  Community_Plan_Area: '-999',
  Specific_Plan_Area: 'Downtown',
  General_Plan_Designation: 'Downtown',
```

I would like to be able to access its properties via JavaScript classes.

Comment: You're extending an object `new DataRepository` not the class `DataRepository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As georg already pointed out, you need to export the class itself in order to extend it.

```
module.exports = DataRepository;
```

Since you seem to want to set a filename, but that filename is hard-coded in the module anyways, you can just set that in the constructor.

```
class DataRepository {
  constructor() {
    this.filename = "cales_data.json";
    try {
      fs.accessSync(this.filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("data does not exist");
    }
  }
...
```